# IE9 Not allowing inputs within button tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, addeventlistener

In Internet Explorer 9, which I understand supports the function `addEventListener`, is giving me a strange error when I try to use the function here:

```
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    }
    else { // No much to do
        elem[evnt] = func;
    }
}
```

(Courtesy of another question here  on SO)

I get the error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the value of the property 'addEventListener': object is null or undefined.

It breaks on the line `if(elem.addEventListener)`

I am passing it `document.getElementById('search')`, which is a text input field; for evnt, I am passing it `keydown`, and for function I am passing:

```
function(e) {
    if (!e) 
    { 
        var e = window.event; 
    }

    // Enter is pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 13) 
    {
        search($("#search").val());
        $("#search").val("");
        $("#search").blur(); 
    }
}
```

I have no problems with this in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, but IE9 is giving me grief.

**Edit**

Okay I've gotten the JS to run properly by putting the eventlistener in inline, but I am still getting a problem, which appears to be the parent problem behind the whole thing here: `document.getElementById('search')` is returning null **only in IE**. It works in *every* other browser, and it is only this *one* element that is returning null.

**Edit 2** - I've updated the question title to reflect the true problem here.

So the root of the problem now is that the `<input>` is not showing up in the HTML at all (though it *does* show up in the source code)...? I have the input field inside of a `<button>`, which works in every other browser perfectly, but not in IE. How can I fix this?

Comment: How sure are you that IE is actually finding the element you think it's finding? In other words, have you used the debugger to check and see what "elem" actually is?

Comment: Where/How do you call `addEvent`

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle or a codepen or a plunker of this?

Comment: @Pointy The developer tools' console is returning null for `document.getElementById('search')`, but I can clearly see it in my HTML...I know it's there...This seems to be the bigger issue.

Comment: The error indicates elem is not recognized as an object with properties, it hasn't got to seeing if it has the property yet.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a very legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not valid to have an `<input>` inside a `<button>` consider putting it inside a `<label>` instead, or a `<span>` with a `click` handler and suitable CSS.

Comment: Replacing button with label worked perfectly! Didn't even have to change my CSS! Thanks!